# Sigma notation (Recursive Series)

Tags: calculus

The recursive series is $1 - 1 + 1/2 - 1/6 + 1/24 - 1/120$.

As of right now, I have $$\sum_{n=0}^5 \frac {(-1)^k}{k!}$$

Comment: $$e^x=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\dfrac{x^r}{r!}$$ Set $r=-1$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Only upto 5 terms it is

Comment: Thanks for the help, but why are you showing $e^x$?

Comment: Note that you can write $\pm b$ or $a\pm b. \qquad$

Comment: It doesn't seem clear what question you're asking. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply $\dfrac{1}{k!}$ 
by
$(-1)^n$ which will alternate for even and odd $n$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!